# Is it correct to use function inside of loop

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to know that is it good practice to call function inside of loop,the following two code, have a same result but i want to make it clear, that's why i want to use function, is it good practice to use? thanks

without function:

```
var json = {
    "lists": [
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "one": "one",
                    "two": "two"

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

json.lists.forEach(function (list) {
    list.items.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item);
    })
});
```

result:{ one: 'one', two: 'two' }

with function:

```
var json = {
    "lists": [
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "one": "one",
                    "two": "two"

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function getItem(list) {
    list.items.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item);
    })
}

json.lists.forEach(function (list) {
    getItem(list)
});
```

result:{ one: 'one', two: 'two' }

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using functions here if it makes your code more readable and easier to maintain. After all, `console.log()` is also a function. You could even write: `json.lists.forEach(getItem)`

Comment: Please, give a precise, unambiguous, objective, verifiable definition of what you mean by "correct". Without such a definition, it is impossible to tell whether your code is correct. How can we tell you whether it is correct, if you don't tell us, what exactly you consider "correct"?

Comment: as i said both works but i want to know which one is more better to use

Comment: Please, give a precise, unambiguous, objective, verifiable definition of what you mean by "better to use". Without such a definition, it is impossible to tell which of your two examples are better to use. How can we tell you which is better to use, if you don't tell us, what exactly you consider "better to use"? What criteria are you using to determine which is "better"? We need to know the criteria, then we can check which of the two pieces fulfills those criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better Debug Capability, anonymous functions is not recommended. So try not to use them:

```
    var json = {
    "lists": [
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "one": "one",
                    "two": "two"

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

    function logSingleItem(item) {
        console.log(item);
    }

    function loopListItem(list) {
        list.items.forEach(logSingleItem)
    }

    json.lists.forEach(loopListItem);
```

Comment: Not using anonymous functions anywhere might be overdoing it a bit.